# FromQuery object mapping

Tags: c#

I have several structure

```
public class TestQuery
{
public int Sort {get;set;}
public Filter Filter {get;set;}
}
```

```
public class Filter
{
public IList<string> Names {get;set;}
}
```

TestQuery get values from URL query params
How i can processing Names array from query params?
Is it possible at all?
How should query string looks like for this structure `query:{sort:1 , filter:{statuses: [a,b,c]}}`

In my case query params string for filter field looks `filter=%5Bobject%20Object%5D`

Comment: Um.. is this Java or C#? This doesn't look like JavaScript.

Comment: @caTS yes, it's C#, but i research also how i can create js model(object) for prepare this url

Comment: [Model Binding in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding?view=aspnetcore-7.0#collections)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

query string would be something like that:

```
https://localhost:7091/?Sort=1&Filter.Names=name1&Filter.Names=name2&Filter.Names=name3
```